# bash: Is there any way of printing two files with a single command?

Tags: bash, cat

I was trying to print two files with a single command.

I have two files: **file1** and **file2**.

I used `cat file1 file2 > together` to combine these two and get a new file **together**.

When I `cat together`, the content of two files is shown on the screen. However, I want to know if there is any way I can print out two files with one single command using `cat`?

Comment: uh... `cat file1 file2` with no redirect *does* print `file1` and `file2` together ?

Comment: @zanna we should make it `dog file1 file2`

Comment: @JacobVlijm ah maybe you found the problem... `cat` got scared and ran away with the files

Comment: I think `cat` is busy chasing the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just running `cat file1 file2` will do what you want.

When you add `> together`, you're telling the shell to send the output into the file `together` instead of printing the output on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is still technically 2 commands, but it would still give a combined, uninterupted output: `cat file1 && cat file2`